# How to make Windows CMD.exe and Powershell behave like terminal in macOS?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I can't stand using the windows shell and am wondering if there's a way to configure it or download an alternative that does these two simple things:

- Left click and drag to highlight some text, then right clicking on that highlighted text and being able to click "copy".
- Right click on the terminal window, and be able to click "paste" to paste text at the current position of the cursor.

I'd also like to be able to do **ctrl** *+* **c** to copy and **ctrl** *+* **v** to paste text.

By default, if I want to copy the selected text, I have to click the icon on the top left corner of the window to open the drop down. There are no other Windows applications that have this behavior, this seems to be some legacy UX design that hasn't changed since 1995.

Also if I right click on the CMD.exe window, my clipboard is pasted into the current position of the curser, I don't like this either.

Any suggestions or advice to help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Command Prompt almost natively supports this.

If you enable quick edit mode, you can make a selection with left mouse button, click with right once to copy, click with right again to paste.

In addition you can activate the ability to copy/paste using CTRL-C and CTRL-V.

Open a command prompt, click on the icon in the top-left corner of the window to bring up the context menu, and select properties.

At the Options tab, below Edit Options, you'll find quick edit mode. In addition, there is a CTRL+Shift+C/V option. Make sure this is unchecked. If checked, instead of CTRL-C and CTRL-V, it will also require the shift to be pressed.